# I am getting a TypeError for using the 'in' keyword on an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

I am attempting to write a helper function for myself to check if a property is inside of a given OBJECT. For my own use case, if I come across an array, then I only have to obtain the first (0 index) array to continue. My helper function is to return a boolean value since it is only checking to see if the provided string will work (or not).

Given the OBJECT:

```
{'object': {
        "promotion": {
            "items": [{
                "startAndEndDate": {
                    "startDate": "2017-11-10",
                    "endDate": "2017-11-29"
                },
                "amount": {
                    "discount": 12
                }
            }]
        }
    }
};
```

My function:

```
var propertyInObjectFuncUtil = function (string, obj) {
            var substringArray = string.split('.');

            if (substringArray.length) {
                try {
                    substringArray.reduce(function (prev, curr) {
                        if (curr in prev) {
                            return prev[curr];
                        } else if (curr in prev[0]) {
                            return prev[0][curr];
                        } else {
                            throw ('These are not droids you are looking for...');
                        }
                    }, obj);

                    return true;
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error);
                    return false;
                }

            }
        };
```

Attempting to make it work with the following:

```
var example1 = propertyInObjectFuncUtil('object.promotion.items.amount.discount',obj) // true
var example2 = propertyInObjectFuncUtil('object.promotion.itemss',obj) // false
var example3 = propertyInObjectFuncUtil('object.promotion.items.startAndEndDate.endDates',obj) //false
```

However I am getting this TypeError:
`TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'itemss' in undefined`

Comment: Please be aware that in your example that is not JSON. Consider using the terminology "object" instead.

Comment: @NickParsons, doesn't `prev` become the returned value as it gets iterated over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the `in` operator cannot be used when the right hand side is `undefined`, it only works on objects. So add a check for those:

```
if (Object(prev) === prev && curr in prev) {
    return prev[curr];
} else if (Array.isArray(prev) && Object(prev[0]) === prev[0] && curr in prev[0]) {
    return prev[0][curr];
} else {
    throw new Error('These are not droids you are looking for...');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

itemss witten with 2 's' does not exist, you cannot iterate over an undefined value.

add a check for null/undefined and you should be fine.

Comment: I understand your point but `prev` is a legitimate object. So `'itemss'` a.k.a. `curr` should fail the first and second `if` conditions and throw an error, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue occurs when you use an invalid path. If your path is invalid, then `curr in obj` will be `false`, thus making you check the next condition. Your first example is working fine, however, your others are not. Consider the values of `prev` over multiple iterations for the path:

```
'object.promotion.itemss'
```

First, `prev` starts off as:

```
{
  'object': {
    "promotion": {
      "items": [{
        "startAndEndDate": {
          "startDate": "2017-11-10",
          "endDate": "2017-11-29"
        },
        "amount": {
          "discount": 12
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

You then check if `'object'` is `in` this object, which is it, so you update prev.

Next iteration your `prev` is now:

```
{
  "promotion": {
    "items": [{
      "startAndEndDate": {
        "startDate": "2017-11-10",
        "endDate": "2017-11-29"
      },
      "amount": {
        "discount": 12
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

You then check to see if `'promotion'` is `in` this object using the first condition of your if, it is, so you update prev.

Third iteration, `prev` is now:

```
{
  "items": [{
    "startAndEndDate": {
      "startDate": "2017-11-10",
      "endDate": "2017-11-29"
    },
    "amount": {
      "discount": 12
    }
  }]
}
```

You now first check to see if `'itemss'` is in this object using your first condition in your if. It is not. So you then check your second condition:

```
} else if (curr in prev[0]) {
```

The issue is here. `prev[0]` is trying to access key `0` in your `prev` object (shown above), however, this key doesn't exist, so `prev[0]` evaluates to `undefined`. Using `curr in undefined` will throw an error as this isn't a valid use case of `in`. Consider checking if `prev[0]` is defined (and an object) before using it with the in operator, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63056554/5648954)

Comment: Thank you for your help!